Is it possible to connect two grounded coplanar waveguides?
On my PCB I have an SMA connector that delivers RF voltage signal (1MHz to 1GHz) from my Arbitrary Waveform Generator (AWG) to my device under test (DUT). The DUT is an IC, wirebonded to my PCB, and the connection on the PCB between the SMA connector and the wirebonds is a grounded coplanar waveguide.
I would like to have the option to send my RF signal to my DUT using an FPC connector, instead of SMA if I choose so. This means that I would like to have both an SMA connector and an FPC connector as inputs to my DUT (2 input channels). If it were a DC signal the wiring would be as simple as connecting the tracks from the FPC and SMA signal pins together, however, since I am looking at RF signals, I can't think of a way to connect the two. Is it even possible?
If I use the SMA path, wouldn't having an open FPC path cause reflections? What about the intersection point of the paths coming from the FPC and SMA connectors?

Does your RF signal carry any DC voltage/current with it?
If not, it's probably a good idea to put a blocking capacitor in the path to prevent any unwanted DC being applied to the DUT.
Then, you can place two capacitors so that their footprints overlap, sharing one pad. The trace to the SMA connects to one of the capacitors and the trace to the FPC connects to the other. Now you just have to load one of the capacitors or the other to connect to the SMA or to the FPC. Most likely you want to just build multiple copies of the board, some for connecting one way, some for the other.
If you do need to connect a DC voltage along with your RF, you can use 0-ohm resistors instead of capacitors. The pattern would look something like this (choose a resistor or capacitor package size such that the pads are the same width as your traces):

If you need to dynamically switch between sources, then you probably want to just use an RF switch or relay.

Note that a 0-ohm jumper resistor can be used in the same way, if DC is required :)

Thank you both! :) I don't need to dynamically switch between sources, but my signal does have a DC component. An example of an RF signal that I am planning to use is a 0-5V peak-to-peak sine wave centered around 2.5V DC. Just out of curiosity, if I put a 0-ohm jumper resistor, isn't it essentially the same as just connecting the RF track from the SMA to the RF track of the FPC? How does adding resistors/capacitors with overlapping footprints prevents reflections from occurring?

@Hikikomori, I've added a drawing. You make the footprint such that there are no stubs, as shown.

@The Photon, thanks for the drawing! Actually, is there a way to have both lines connected? If I understand correctly, if I would like to use the FPC connector and currently the SMA is connected using the jumper resistor, I will need to resolder the resistor in the other position. I have 8 SMA channels so it would be a bit of work to resolder.

@Hikikomori, it might be more convenient to just assemble two boards, with one configured to use SMA and one for FPC.
